# Rebuilding the script from cURL to multi cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to implement some multi cURL functions instead of simple cURL functions.

I have the following snippet:

```
$curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING,'gzip'); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $rv = ($returnArray) ? json_decode($result, true) : json_decode($result);
```

It gives me results ($result returns success and some data). I want to rewrite it to use curl_multi_init(). I tried this:

```
$curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING,'gzip'); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $mh = curl_multi_init();
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$curl);


        $running= \null;
        do {
           curl_multi_exec($mh,$running);
           $result = curl_multi_exec($mh,$running);
        } while($running > 0);
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $curl);

        curl_multi_close($mh);
        $rv = ($returnArray) ? json_decode($result, true) : json_decode($result);
```

I get no results ($result is empty). I have no errors whatsoever. What is wrong?

Comment: RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php - `curl_multi_exec()` returns an `int` not an array of results

Answer (score 0):

**This Works for me :**

```
function get_result( $nodes )
    {
        $node_count = count($nodes);

        $curl_arr = array();
        $master = curl_multi_init();

        for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
        {
            $url = $nodes[$i];
            $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
            curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);
        }

        do {
            curl_multi_exec($master,$running);
            curl_multi_select($master, 5.0);
        } while($running > 0);


        $output = "";
        for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
        {
            $output .= curl_multi_getcontent( $curl_arr[$i]  ) . "<breaktag>";
            curl_multi_remove_handle( $master, $curl_arr[$i] );
            curl_close( $curl_arr[$i] );
        }

        curl_multi_close( $master );

        return $output;
    }


    $nodes[] = ()  // your URLs
    $responses = get_result( $nodes );
    $responses = explode("<breaktag>", $responses);  //now responses is array of result
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't use this approach. I have to strictly assign the curl_multi_exec($mh,$running) to $result variable. I can't go too wild :(